# Android Handler created in Fragment's onCreate() not executing handleMessage() on UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, handler

In my Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Handler uiHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle data = msg.getData();
            String text = data.getString("event");
            mTextView.setText(text);
        }
    };

    server = new ServerClass(uiHandler);
```

In onCreateView() I set mTextView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById((R.id.event));
}
```

Relevant parts of ServerClass:

```
public class ServerClass {
    private Handler mHandler;
    public GameServer(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void startServer(final int server_port) {
        serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Socket socket = null;
                Bundle data;
                Message msg;

                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(server_port);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        data = new Bundle();
                        data.putString("event", "new connection");

                        msg = new Message();
                        msg.setData(data);
                        mHandler.handleMessage(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        serverThread.start();
    }
}
```

My understanding was that since the handler was created in the UI thread - in the Fragment's onCreate() - that handleMessage() in that handler should also be executed on the UI thread, but that is not happening. When I get a new connection I get the following error:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Following the rest of the stack trace ends up pointing at the line containing `mTextView.setText(text);` in handleMessage() as the cause.

I have tried are to set the handler with getMainLooper but that did not help:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
    // ...
```

I've also tried creating the handler in onCreateView() instead but still got the same error.

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious, this has me pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

Becuase calling `handleMessage` method using Handler object from non-ui thread.

To send message from non-ui Thread use `Handler.sendMessage` method:

```
                    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                    data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("event", "new connection");
                    msg.setData(data);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks, such a dumb mistake - that was totally it. I spent so much time looking at this and never noticed I accidentally put handleMessage there instead of sendMessage. Thanks again, need to wait another 5 minutes before I can accept your answer.